# Load jQuery não captura dados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,
Fiz uma página de cadastro, onde consigo consular origem e destinatario, funcionando perfeitamente.

Agora estou fazendo a página de edição. Como já tenho o cpf_cnpj de origem e destino, preciso que getJSON, faça a consulta de imediato mostrando os valores.

Quando a pagina é carregada, os campo são preenchidos:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    executa2();
    $("#cpf_cnpj2").on('blur load',executa2);

    function executa2(){
       nome=$("#cpf_cnpj2").val();

        $.getJSON("cotacoesBuscaCliente.php", {cpf_cnpj:nome}, function(json){


            $("#cpf_cnpj2").val(json[0].cpf_cnpj);
            $("#isento2").val(json[0].isento);
            $("#suframa2").val(json[0].suframa);
            $("#rsocial2").val(json[0].rsocial);
            $("#nfantasia2").val(json[0].nfantasia);
            $("#ie2").val(json[0].ie);
            $("#im2").val(json[0].im);
            $("#cep2").val(json[0].cep);
            $("#rua2").val(json[0].rua);
            $("#num2").val(json[0].num);
            $("#comple2").val(json[0].comple);
            $("#bairro2").val(json[0].bairro);
            $("#cidade2").val(json[0].cidade);
            $("#estado2").val(json[0].estado);
            $("#pais2").val(json[0].pais);


        });
    };

});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora esse código deve pega o valor do  campo Estado `#estado2` (Imagem acima) para passar ao getJSON, mas isso não acontece quando a página é carregada.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    executa3();
    $('.transportadora, .destino, .tabbable').on('load click', executa3);
    function executa3(){
       id       = $("input[type=radio][name='transportadora']:checked").val();
        estado  = $("#estado2").val();
        peso    = $("#maiorPeso").val();
        destino = $("input[type=radio][name='destino']:checked").val();


        $.getJSON("cotacoesBuscaTransportadora.php", {id_transportadora:id, estado:estado, peso:peso, destino:destino}, function(json){


            $("#estadoT").val(json[0].estadoT);
            $("#valorCap").val(json[0].valorT);
            $("#valorExcedCap").val(json[0].valorExced);
            $("#adValorem").val(json[0].valorAlorem);
            $("#prazoCap").val(json[0].prazo);

            var GETEstado = json[0].GETEstado;
            var ResulteZero = json[0].ResulteZero;

            //if (GETEstado == ""){
            //  $.gritter.add({
            //      title: 'Erro',
            //      text: 'Preencha os dados do destinatário',
            //      class_name: 'gritter-error'
            //  });
            //}

            if (ResulteZero == 0) {
                $.gritter.add({
                    title: 'Erro',
                    text: 'Essa transportadora não entrega no estado de destino ou destino não preenchido.',
                    class_name: 'gritter-error'
                });
            }

            if (json[0].valorAlorem == "") {
                $.gritter.add({
                    title: 'Erro',
                    text: 'Essa transportadora não faz entrega "Fluvial" ou não existe cadastro do mesmo.',
                    class_name: 'gritter-error'
                });
            };


        });
    };

});
```

Como é uma página de edição, o Estado deve passar para o `getJSON` assim que a página é carregada, mas não consigo, somente quando executo a ação de `click`, que funciona.

Vendo pelo inspetor do chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se deixar **input #estado2** declarado  no html `value="RJ"` funciona. Parece que o **executa3()** não consegue pegar o valor inserido pelo **executa2()** no input.

Comment: Posta a parte do formulário que possui o `#estado2`

Comment: @MaiconCarraro O html?

Comment: Sim, mas não tudo, só que for relevante

Comment: `<input name="estado2" id="estado2" type="text" class="form-control" value="" readonly />`

Comment: Tenta tirar o readonly só para ver. @Thiago

Comment: O `executa3` não está sendo executado antes do `executa2`?

Comment: Ja tentei sem o `readonly`. A ordem é essa mesma que coloquei acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tiago**, o que está acontecendo provavelmente é que seu `executa3()` está sendo chamado ANTES do seu `executa2()`.

Você tem duas opções:

1. Utilizar um `callback` em `executa2(callback)` e depois chamá-lo ao final do preenchimento dos campos
2. Pode também manter a ordem de carregamento exatamente assim: `executa2() -> executa3()` e desativar a opção "asynchronous" `async: false` nas opções do `ajax`.

**OPÇÃO "CALLBACK"**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function executa2(callback){
       nome=$("#cpf_cnpj2").val();

        $.getJSON("cotacoesBuscaCliente.php", {cpf_cnpj:nome}, function(json){


            $("#cpf_cnpj2").val(json[0].cpf_cnpj);
            $("#isento2").val(json[0].isento);

            // (...) restante do executa2()

            if (typeof callback != 'undefined')
                callback(); // aqui estamos executando executa3() que foi passado pelo parâmetro

        });
    };


    $("#cpf_cnpj2").on('blur load',

            executa2(function() // aqui estamos chamando executa2() para execução e ao mesmo tempo passando executa3() como parâmetro
            {
                $('.transportadora, .destino, .tabbable').on('load click', executa3);

                function executa3(){

                    id       = $("input[type=radio][name='transportadora']:checked").val();

                    // (...) restante do executa3()

                };
            });

    );

});
```

**Obs.**: Você pode também declarar ambas as funções e simplesmente chamar `executa2(executa3())`, mantendo obviamente a chamada do callback no final do ajax do `executa2()`

**OPÇÃO ASYNC EM AMBAS AS REQUISIÇÕES AJAX**

Note `async: false`:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  async: false,
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
});
```

Explicação: com `async: false`, a requisição ajax segue uma "fila" e não é executado em concorrência (causando o risco de um ser executado antes do outro)

Comment: `async: false` é de evitar...

Comment: Não é esse o problema. Eu fiz um teste, no input #estado2 deixei declarado `value="RJ"`, ai ele carrega certinho. Parece que o **executa3();** não esta conseguindo pegar o valor que o **executa2();** coloca no input.

Comment: Tentou digitar pelo console `$('#estado2').val()` ?

Comment: Sim, da RJ, http://i.imgur.com/UEwoxjr.png

Comment: @Tiago, tentou chamar `console.log(estado)` em `executa3()` logo após ele ser declarado?

Comment: Não, como devo fazer?

Comment: Parece que o problema esta em pegar o valo do `input` #estado2

Comment: @Tiago exato, este é o problema. Mas lembre-se que ele é preenchido ANTES pelo `executa2()`. Então precisamos saber se ao passar pelo ajax do `executa3()`, se o valor do mesmo é válido. Você pode inserir `console.log(estado)` logo embaixo de `destino = $("input[type=radio][name='destino']:checked").val();`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25174/discussion-between-tiago-and-felipe-douradinho).

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho Estou no chat